# What is the purpose of the "organization name" when deploying things through CI/CD on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Sorry if this description seems confusing because I actually have no idea what's going on, so I don't actually know if I'm asking the right questions.

Here are the screenshots of what I'm talking about; https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfDWH.jpg.

So I'm trying to deploy a function to Azure using Azure Pipelines connected to a github repository. In the first picture, what is the point/meaning of the Azure Devops Organization field? I left some organizations through aex.dev.azure.com which is why it's bugging out and not loading. But before I did that, I selected the org I was part of and it would show other projects that were a part of that organization. But this function isn't related, so I didn't want to do that. So why can't I add a new project to an existing organization?

Then I switched over to the "new" tab in the second picture. In the organization field, it only lets you specify a non-existing organization. So say I already have an org called "myOrg". I can't put that as the organization.

So with these restrictions, basically every single time I want to deploy something to Azure Pipelines, I need to create another organization. So that would be one organization per deployment and that org would only have one project listed under there.

1. What is the purpose of this organization abstraction?
2. How can I add a deployment as a new project in an existing organization?
3. Or do I just have to make a new organization for every new deployment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose of this organization abstraction?

The organization in azure devops is just like a user base, you can set who can access or do some operation in this organization. The purpose is to manage.

> How can I add a deployment as a new project in an existing
> organization?

Off course, but the premise is your azure account have the access permission to the organization. Then dont forget to go out of the Deployment Center and re-authorize.

> Or do I just have to make a new organization for every new deployment?

No, you dont need.

This is the structure:

[image]

Before deploy, you need to create the repository first in azure devops.

Let me know whether you can deploy in exist organization now.:)

Comment: Thanks so much!. I understand now. I guess I didn't realize I had to initialize a repository in Azure DevOps first because I was pulling the code from a GitHub repository.